# Android: Chronometer Starting From Start of Activity and Not From Button Click

Tags: android

I have a chronometer and I would like it to start counting from when the user clicks a button and not from the start of the activity. Currently, when the user clicks the button to start the timer from 0, it just shows the time from the activity started. Here is the relevant code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.startTimer: {
            Chronometer stopWatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono);
            startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

            timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
            stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                    countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
                    String asText = (countUp / 60) + ":" + (String.format("%02d", (countUp % 60))); 
                    timer.setText(asText);
                }
            });
            stopWatch.start();
            break;
        }
...
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what arg0.getBase is, but I think you want to change --

```
countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
```

to

```
countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime) / 1000;
```

because startTime is the time the button was clicked.

Comment: The code was from online because I was trying to find out how to do a "count-up" timer and it works from that (without the case, onclick, etc). I was trying to adapt it so it would only run when the button was clicked. I am testing now...

Answer (score -1):

you can add

```
stopWatch.setBase(startTime);
```

just below

```
startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

So, your updated code will be like,...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.startTimer: {
        Chronometer stopWatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono);
        startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        // this line to be added to the code
         stopWatch.setBase(startTime);


        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerText);
        stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
                String asText = (countUp / 60) + ":" + (String.format("%02d", (countUp % 60))); 
                timer.setText(asText);
            }
        });
        stopWatch.start();
        break;
    }
...
```

Hope this helps..